# ldap filter work on JXeplorer, but no in php

Tags: php, ldap

i have this filter:

> (&(DomainLogin=ara*)(&((!(DomainLogin=ara_test_7))(!(DomainLogin=ara_test_8))(!(DomainLogin=ara_test_10))(!(DomainLogin=ara_test_11)))))

if i use this filter on JXplorer work fine and i find the result, but if i use a php ldap_list i have this error:

> Warning: ldap_list() [function.ldap-list]: Search: Bad search filter

```
<?
$f="(&(DomainLogin=ara*)(&((!(DomainLogin=ara_test_7))(!(DomainLogin=ara_test_8))(!(DomainLogin=ara_test_10))(!(DomainLogin=ara_test_11)))))";
$g=ldap_list($conn,$page->ldap_search_dn,$f,array(),false,10);
print_r(ldap_get_entries($conn,$g));
?>
```

why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this filter: `(&(DomainLogin=ara*)(&(!(DomainLogin=ara_test_7))(!(DomainLogin=ara_test_8))(!(DomainLogin=ara_test_10))(!(DomainLogin=ara_test_11))))`

Comment: Complex, multi-component filters can get a little funky.